# How to change part of a web page without reloading a whole page correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I tried to invoke a function of javascript to make a php page change with the navigation bar, without realoading the whole page, but the closes i've been into is I succed to do that with a button command but the javascript inside the page is turned off, what did I do wrong?

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
$('#button_1, #button_2, #button_3, #button_4').click(function(){
                var which_to_load = ( $(this).attr('id')+"" ).replace('button_', ''),
                source_of_file = 'content'+which_to_load+'.php';
                $('#content_box').load( source_of_file );
                return false;
            });
});
     </script>
```

Link part:

```
<div id="content_changing_buttons">
     <form method="get" id="change_content_buttons" action="">
       <p>
        <li><input value="1" type="submit" id="button_1" name="page" /> Reggiani presents at frankfurt Light + Build 2012</a><br/><br /></li>
        <li><input value="2" type="submit" id="button_2" name="page" /> Reggiani presents at frankfurt Light + Build 2012</a><br/><br /></li>
        <li><input value="3" type="submit" id="button_3" name="page" /> Reggiani presents at frankfurt Light + Build 2012<br/><br /></li>
        <li><input value="4" type="submit" id="button_4" name="page" /> Reggiani presents at frankfurt Light + Build 2012<br/><br /></li>
       </p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

And the content part:

```
  // default number of page to load
        $defaultPageNumber = '2';
        // check if content number is set
        $numberOfPageToInclude = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : $defaultPageNumber;

        $options = array(
            'options' => array(
                'min_range' => 1,
                'max_range' => 4,
                ));

        if (filter_var($numberOfPageToInclude, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) !== FALSE) {
            include ('content' . $numberOfPageToInclude . '.php');
        } else {
            echo '<span style="color:red;">Wrong page number, including default page!</span><br />';
            include 'content1.php';
        }
        ?>
 </div>
```

Now I have done like it was suggested, but when i invoke the code, at first the default php page showed up, then when i clicked the button to change the php side of the page, it worked but somehow it turned off the rest of the javascript, even my accordion js and blinds js (that it reffered from another php page) suddenly turned off.

Anyone can suggest how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with firebug? for javascript to stop working usually the response the php generated must contain buggy javascript itself.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but im quite new to this, I do not know how to debug the j query itself, but if there is anything wrong with my script initialization above, like to know how to fix it, because it seems, if I took of one function, it will work, so how do I run 2 function of the script without overlapping each other?

Comment: you can actually use chrome as well, just press F12 and then click on the Console tab, then refresh your page and click away, when the page stops working the console should have listed something. You can also install http://www.chromephp.com/ it is very simple to use and have good examples about printing to the debug console from within the php code. In javascript you would simply type console.log("hello world"); But when loading an external page as php that generates javascript console.log can become tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <html>
          <head>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          function showentry()
             {
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
             else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                   {
                      document.getElementById("right").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                   }
                }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","details.php",true);//whatever the contents of file                                       details.php displayed in right div
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
             </script>
             <style type="text/css">
                #left{width:500px;height:100%; float:left;}
                #right{width:500px; float:left;}
             </style>
           </head>
       <div id="left">
      <input type="button" name="GET" value="show" onclick="showentry()"/>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
        </div>
        </html>
```